# Prevent equal height to dynamic width div from overlaping content below

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Anyone know how I can prevent an equal height to dynamic width div from overlapping the content below. The div needs to expand to contain content in narrow viewports.

@caeth suggested moving the div below to be inside the div above, which works: http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/5/ but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require this.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape_outer">
<div class="shape_inner">Content...</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="shape_below"></div>
```

...

```
.holder {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}
.shape {
margin-top: 100%;
}
.shape_outer {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
.shape_inner {
background: #ddd;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.shape_below {
background: #111;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

and a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/4/

Thanks B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.shape {
  margin:20px;
}
```

What you are doing is create a hidden field around the `div`.I think you can delete the `shape-outer`.

Comment: That doesn't do it — it would also remove the height that is equal to the width.

Comment: You can do it with `position: absolute;` and then set the position, but that kills responsiveness..